# Send app invite request for a website to all friends of user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-requests

I implemented a custom friends selector to send app invite requests for my website to a user's FB friends. But that show no of limitations, first that invitation may be sent to at max 50 people. I have seen  games on FB sending app invite requests to user's all friends, wont that same kind of invite work for my website ?

Secondly Using the requests dialog with friend selector, there is no way to select **all** friends for invite. How could I make it better towards sending app invites to user's all friends ?

At some places in the FB devlopers docs, they mention explicity games & apps on facebook. If I am a website with a FB canvas page as well. Can I use the services availble for games on facebook? (Is it Legal ?)

Answer (score 2):

App requests are for games, not for sharing a website.

The only serious (and not spammy) way to share a website on Facebook is to use the Send or Share Dialogs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share

You may want to read this too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: thanx for the link, i´ll add it to the answer

Comment: but I've seen many popular websites exploiting this like glassdoor,  meritnation & so many others ??

Comment: "others do it too" is not a good argument ;) - and exploiting is never a good idea.

Comment: I mean to ask if is it not allowed(legally) or is it just not designed for that use ?

Comment: first of all, it´s bad practice and annoying for users to send them app requests for websites - they ARE for games. app requests always go to the canvas page first, you can´t just link to your website. and creating a canvas page just to redirect to an external website is definitely not allowed - so yeah, it´s not allowed :)

Comment: i just checked out glassdoor does it & clicking on app request generated notification/app  takes to canvas page which redirects to main website\

Comment: as i said: "others do it too" is not a good argument - and it´s not allowed, so don´t do it ;) > https://developers.facebook.com/policy/